# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Android application does not connect to server after july security update

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am using Worklight 6.0.0.2, download about 1 month ago from http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/

The Build is 20140718-1713, and I installed it after reading the security note : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/action_required_cordova_android_security_update?lang=en

Now When I test on device, I always have 404 error when connecting to the worklight server (calling adapters)

I tested on multiple devices, with 2 servers, and it's the same.

When observing changes, I noticed that `android/native/libs/cordova.jar` and `native/libs/worklight-android.jar` changed. So, I have replaced them with the old files, and the Android binary file connects again with Worklight Server without any problem!

I see that the public version for Worklight 6.0.0.2 has not changed yet since 21 July, which mean I have the latest public version. Is there any fix ? Does any one else encountered the same issue ?

Comment: Did you also apply the fixpack to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did the config.xml template for the Android whitelist contain the value ".* " ? Where it should be "*" (without the leading dot).

Please see Section 3.) Modify the Cordova whitelist under https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/action_required_cordova_android_security_update?lang=en

Comment: Adding my servers URLs to whitelist fixed the issue.